# searching a line in a txt file

Tags: php

I have a txt file in the server and it contains lines sth like that

```
one
two
three
four
five
```

i want to make a function that checks if a word exists in these lines.

any help is appreciated.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you may proceed with it:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('yourfile.txt');
$search_keyword =  'four';

// check if word is there
if (strpos($contents, $search_keyword) !== FALSE){
  echo "$search_keyword was found !!";
}
else{
  echo "$search_keyword was NOT found !!";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this really need to be done in php? You've just described the UNIX `grep` utility.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like:

```
$data = file($path_to_file,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

if (in_array($data,'word')) {
  // do something
}
```

That is a simple hack but it should work.